# Call vs Delegate Call call data format

Tags: solidity, calldata, assembly, delegatecall

I'm using both `call` and `delegatecall` within an assembly block and i've noticed that when issuing a `call` I need to provide 4 bytes (sig) + any arguments, whereas for `delegatecall` I need to provide 4 bytes (sig) + 32 bytes of zeros and then my arguments.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Does it have something to do with using `delegatecall` for libraries which expect the contract state to be the first argument?